# string format negative hexadecimal

Tags: c#, hex, string.format

Is there a way to custom format a string for a negative hexadecimal?

I would like a format to show up like -$1,X or $A,X. if a value is 0xff I want it to appear as -$1. The value is a signed value. and I notice that {0:X2} would display it as 'ff' instead of '-1'.

Comment: So you want it formatted in hex if positive, and in decimal if negative?

Comment: Really I would like it formatted in hex, but with the negative sign and 2's complemented if bit 8 is set.

Comment: Another example would be -$59 instead of $ffa7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I really understand your question.  Lets assume that you are dealing with items of type sbyte (since it is the only type that makes sense in the context).  You could create a method like this:

```
String FormatByte(sbyte b) {
    return (b & 0x80) == 0x80 ? String.Format("-${0}", -b) : String.Format("${0:X}", b);
    }
```

Which when called with a -59 returns -$59 and when called with 10 returns $A

Comment: Close, but it would return -$10 instead of -$A.

Comment: resolved by changing the first String.Format("-${0}", -b) to also be -${0:X}